# Optional semicolon in C++

Tags: c++

The following code compiled fine (without semicolon after each line). Why are semicolons not needed at the end of each lines under the public section?

Note: putting a semicolon after each lines is fine also, so it seems like using semicolon here is optional.

```
template<typename T>

class Accessor {

    public:

        explicit Accessor(const T& data) : value(data) {}

        Accessor& operator=(const T& data) { value = data; return *this; }
        Accessor& operator=(const Accessor& other) { this->value = other.value; return *this; }
        operator T() const { return value; }
        operator T&() { return value; }

    private:

        Accessor(const Accessor&);
        T value;
};
```

Comment: These statements are function (method) definitions. You do not need to put `;` after the body of a function.

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785686/in-c-classes-why-the-semi-colon-after-the-closing-brace

Comment: IIRC, `-pedantic` on GCC complains if you put a semicolon after a function definition.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need semicolons after a method definition.

The reason a semicolon is needed after a class definition is that you can declare instances of the class right after the definition:

```
class X
{

} x;

//x is an object of type X
```

For method, this argument obviously doesn't hold, so a semicolon would be redundant (although legal).

Comment: +1. Good explanation. So it's real reason for class/struct and enums require a ; after bracket :)

Comment: what about when we omit the semicolon after  Accessor(const Accessor&) Isn't this a method ?  if we omit the semicolon, the compiler will not compiled.

Comment: @ZzzZz That is a member function declaration which needs to be defined somewhere in the program. while the others as mentioned in my answer are member function definitions written inside the class.

Comment: @ZzzZz if it's only a declaration, you need a semicolon. A definition means the method has a body.

Comment: @Jack yes, of course. You'll find there are few redundant things in C++.

Answer (score 7):

Your code is correct.  That's just how the language works; you don't need semicolons after the body of a method/function implementation.

If you add the semicolons, nothing bad happens because an empty statement with a semicolon is like a no-op. For example, `x += y;;` is legal C++.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to put a semicolon after the closing bracket of a method declaration. In most of the code I've seen there no such semicolon.

Comment: This is not correct, if a semicolon is omitted before main(), it will not compiled.

Comment: What do you mean before main()? Are you referring to a main() in the same file, after the class declaration?

Comment: yes.  I am referring to a main() in the same file, after the class declaration.

Comment: @ZzzZz: but that's not what this answer said. It said that you don't need the semicolon after a **function** declaration. :)

Comment: that's because that's a class definition, not a method definition.

Comment: That's because you **do** need semicolons after class definitions.  It is just part of the rules of the language.

Comment: well, if you omit the semicolon after Accessor(const Accessor&) It is wrong also (will not compiled), and  Accessor(const Accessor&)  is a method definition.

Comment: @ZzzZz: `Accessor(const Accessor&)` is *not* a method definition.  `Accessor(const Accessor&) {}` is, and no semi-colon needed.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear,

```
explicit Accessor(const T& data) : value(data) {}
```

is equivalent to

```
explicit Accessor(const T& data)
:value(data) // initializer list
{
}
```

Which is a member function definition. Here putting a semicolon at the end of the function signature makes it a member *function declaration* that needs to be defined somewhere in the program outside the class like below

```
Accessor::Accessor(const T& data)
{
    // some code
}
```

Also, as the other answer suggests, the end of a function body does not require a semicolon after the closing brace( the end of *class or structure definitions* does require it) but adding one at the end is not going to make a difference as it is considered as no-op and that is the reason why you can add semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Because the C++ rules do not require a semicolon after `}` in function/methods declarations.

Comment: end of brackets usually denote end of a section, such as end of a class statement; therefore, if this is followed by the main () function without a semicolon after the last class statement, the compiler will not compiled.