# Why does the compiler complain about the code

Tags: c++, c, arm

I do not understand the cause of the error:

```
"/pkg/qct/software/arm/RVDS/5.01BLD94/include/assert.h", line 40: Error:  #18: expected a ")"
  extern _ARMABI_NORETURN void abort(void);
```

The code is as follow:

```
28 #ifndef __assert_h                                                              
29 #   define __assert_h                                                           
30 #define _ARMABI_NORETURN __declspec(__nothrow) __declspec(__noreturn)           
31 #define __ARMCLIB_VERSION 410000                                                
32 #   undef __CLIBNS                                                              
33 #   ifdef __cplusplus                                                           
34         namespace std {                                                         
35 #           define __CLIBNS ::std::                                             
36             extern "C" {                                                        
37 #   else                                                                        
38 #       define __CLIBNS                                                         
39 #   endif  /* __cplusplus */                                                    
40     extern _ARMABI_NORETURN void abort(void);                                   
41     extern _ARMABI_NORETURN void __aeabi_assert(const char *, const char *, int)
   __attribute__((__nonnull__(1,2)));                                              
42 #   ifdef __cplusplus                                                           
43             }  /* extern "C" */                                                 
44         }  /* namespace std */                                                  
45 #   endif                                                                       
46 #else                                                                           
47 #   undef assert                                                                
48 #   undef __promise                                                             
49 #endif
```

The code is from RVDS. I do not think there is a bug in the header file of the  compiler.

Comment: error maybe in your code not in `assert.h` file.

Comment: What happens if there is only one line in source file, `#include <assert.h>`?

Comment: Yes OP should try @Dialecticus suggestion.

Comment: @Dialecticus The compiler does not complain after I remove a header file. But I do not know why because the removed header file includes several other header files. I am curious about the possible reasons.

Comment: The problem is most likely at the end of the last included header before the `#include <assert.h>`, because that's what is immediately before the compiler error. Very often the problem is that class declaration [lacks a semicolon](http://stackoverflow.com/q/785686/395718).